# How to manipulate Html.ActionLink to show a link to another controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, actionlink

In the Details view of the HomeController, I'd like to create a link to the Email view on the MiscController.  In addition, I need to add an item to the QueryString.

I'd like to create a link that goes something like:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com/misc/SendMail?id=6">
    <font size="1">Report problems</font>
</a>
```

I've tried the following:

```
<% Html.ActionLink("<font size=\"1\">Report</font>", "SendMail", "Misc", Model.ImageID, new object()); %>
```

It returned no link.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you missed the `=` after the `<%`. That's why it didn't output anything.

Also, the way you passed `routeValues` parameter was wrong.

It should be :

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("<font size=\"1\">Report</font>", "SendMail", "Misc", 
    new { id = Model.ImageID }, null /*htmlAttributes*/) %>
```

Please keep in mind though the `text` argument will be encoded in the output, so there's no point in sending HTML with that argument.
It's best to use CSS to style your HTML.

For example :

```
a.myLink {font-size: 0.5em;color:yellow;}
```

And to set the class attribute for the anchor element :

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Report", "SendMail", "Misc", 
    new { id = Model.ImageID }, new { @class = "myLink" }) %>
```